# How to Provide Multiple name for same Component in Spring Framework?

Tags: spring

I find that a bean can have multiple name like:

`@Bean(name={"bean1",bean2,...}`

Is there any way so that we can have multiple name with component anotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, there is a ticket for this: [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11402)

You have to declare your bean inside @Configuration with @Bean({"b1", "b2"}).